# How do I recover my Grub 2 installation? The BIOS broke it

Tags: partitioning, grub, gparted, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 on my hard disk and I had one boot loader for both of them, which is Grub2. I had some problems with my bios and hard disk that Led to my issue with Grub. I installed my previous Linux on the sda5 partition and hence I want to recover its Grub.

And please provide me with some resources on how to recover the Grub 2?

EDIT: 
i followed the instructions in this [site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351) in response to 'suicideducky' answer 
and i found that this is the device (hd0,4) but when trying setup (hd0,4) it returned Error 12: Invalid device requested

Update: i sucssefuly done what is in the above with site but while the boot time the grub give me and error called Error 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot up an Ubuntu 10.10 Live CD and open a terminal.  Then type this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda5
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/sda5
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sda5 /dev/sda
```

(hd0,4) in GRUB 1 corresponds to (hd0,5) in GRUB 2, which Maverick uses, and both correspond to the first logical partition of your first drive, which is /dev/sda5 in normal (non-GRUB) Linux parlance.

(Credit: [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708))

Comment: Could not find device for /boot: Not found or not a block device. :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to chrooting into the partition first, which is a bit more than you probably want to do.  I updated and corrected my answer on the assumption you aren't going to do that.

Comment: thx, i am trying it:)

Comment: still printing the same Error 17 :S

Comment: hmm; I looked up Error 17, and one blogger says that it might be a messed up device order.  How that happens I don't know, but I have seen it before.  You can perhaps try the advice here: http://stringofthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/grub-error-17-debianubuntu/ .  Only the part about fixing the drive order that is; for GRUB still follow the advice above, if it turns out that was indeed the problem.

Comment: I tried it but the same error remains :S:S

Comment: Mind giving the output of running `sudo fdisk -l` from the live CD?

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/2N0FuifG

Comment: Now FIXED!! ... i used smartmontools to fix bad sectors and it works!!

Comment: Glad you were able to find and fix the problem!